# Why can .end() return an invalid iterator instead of being evaluated every time (like .size()) and checking if it's still valid?

Tags: c++

I recently learned about iterator invalidaiton in c++. I fail to understand why a `.end()` function in a for loop can return an invalid iterator, when, because it's a for loop, it should result in a function call to `.end()` every time the loop runs, just as a index based for loop would with `.size()`.

Is there some kind of caching going on under the hood? Is `.end()` not called every time? Could we fix invalidated iterators if the `.end()` function would check if the iterator had changed in the previous loop iteration?

What is happening and most importantly, why is there a difference (with `.size()`)?

Example code where I have to explitly update the iterator:

```
std::vector<int> v {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
    if (*it == 5 && std::next(it) == v.end()) {
        v.resize(v.size() + 1);
        it = std::next(v.begin(), v.size() - 2);
        *std::next(it) = 999;
        *it = 0;
    }
}
```

If I dont do `it = std::next(v.begin(), v.size() - 2);` after resizing, the iterator is invalid.

The `.size()` indexed loop variant, doesn't have to do that:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    if (v.at(i) == 5 and (i+1) == v.size()) {
        v.resize(v.size() + 1);
        v.at(i + 1) = 999;
        v.at(i) = 0;
    }
}
```

Update: thank you for the explanation in the answer and comments. It's not the `.end()` function that makes the iterator invalid. It's the entire `it` object that is invalid, and I somehow missed the fact that the begin statement in a for loop, the `auto it = v.begin()` is not done before every iteration. Thinking logically, how could a loop even work then...

Comment: It would help if you could [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which illustrates your problem.

Comment: It is a function that gets called. I'm not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Updated with example code

Comment: `.end()` does not return an invalid iterator, it returns a valid iterator that cannot be dereferenced because it is one past the last valid element.

Comment: The second code calls `size()` each time the loop iterates, just like `end()`.  So I don't know what you are expecting here.

Comment: From your examples (thank you), it appears you are having trouble grasping the ramifications of iterator invalidation, not with `.end()`.  The iterator becomes invalidated when you do certain operations on the container.  The first example shows how to make the just invalidated `it` iterator become valid again.

Comment: Concider for some containers `--c.end();` and `c.end() - 1` should to be valid.

Comment: @Eljay that is indeed what I fail to understand. I understand that iterators can be invalidated, but why does the loop not pick that up automatically the next iteration? Does it not execute it = v.begin() and it != v.end() every time, is there some sort of caching?

Comment: `Does it not execute it = v.begin() every time` no, the first expression in the `for(<this>; ; )` is run only once when entering the loop, so `it = v.begin()` is run once.

Comment: The iterator `it` "caches" it's current location.  If the container *moves*, the cache that `it` has is invalidated.

Comment: @KamilCuk so it's not the .end() that return the invalid stuff, the whole `it` is just some totally different object. Therefore, it's invalid.

Comment: Yes. (? you have written in your question "the iterator is invalid" yet you seem to ask about if the container is invalid. Container is valid at all times. The iterator in the container becomes invalid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `std::vector<int>` is a wrapper around an array `int *` that is dynamically allocated. So let's take a look how to iterate over an array.

We can iterate using the size. Here the `6` corresponds in your code to `v.size()`:

```
int *v = new int[6]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    // do something with `v[i]`
}
delete[] v;
```

The same loop can be rewritten using pointers. Similarities to `std::vector`: `v.end()` is `v = 6`, `v.begin()` is `v` and `std::vector<int>::iterator` is `int *`:

```
int *v = new int[6]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (int *it = v; it != v + 6; ++it) {
    // do something with it
}
delete[] v;
```

Now when we resize an array, we allocate new memory and copy the data and free old memory and reassign the pointer to new region of memory:

```
int *v = new int[6]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (int *it = v; it != v + 6; ++it) {
    if (*it == 5 and it + 1 == v + 6) {
       // resize
       {
          int *temp = new int[7]; // allocate new array
          std::copy(v, v + 6, temp); // copy elements
          delete[] v; // delete old array
          v = temp; // reassign pointer
       }
       // Oops! `it` points into `v` that was `delete[]`d above!
    }
}
delete[] v;
```

Because the old array is deleted, the pointer `it` is invalid, it points to a memory that was freed.

Comment: Why does the for loop not pick up that v has changed when the next loop occurs?

Comment: `for loop not pick up` I do not think I understand - a "for loop" is a language construct, not a "thinking" entity. How should it be able to "pick up"? The new pointer `v` is evaluated each loop, but `it` points to the memory region that was freed.

Comment: When the next for loop occurs, `it` (in the scenario where you **don't** fix it by pointing it back to its position in the new location of the vector) is unaware that it has been invalidated, and would be incremented to the next invalid location where the vector no longer exists, and then that invalidate location would be compared to the valid `.end()` and not match.

Comment: Note that C++ iterators could have been smarter, and check for that condition.  But that comes at an additional cost, and C++ (like C) has the primary goal of being as fast as possible.  That overhead for verifying the pointer is valid is contrary to the performance promise of the language, so the programmer is responsible for keeping it valid.  (C++ is not a nanny language, and gives the programmer enough rope to shoot themself in the foot.)